# MySql for conditional Count

Tags: mysql, database

The input is:

```
+--------+-------+----------+----------+
| RESULT | EXMID | EXSUBJID | SID      |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+
|     11 |     4 |        6 | Student4 |
|     12 |     4 |        6 | Student3 |
|     25 |     4 |        6 | Student5 |
|     45 |     4 |       10 | Student8 |
|     12 |     4 |       10 | Student4 |
|    100 |     4 |       10 | Student5 |
|     12 |     4 |       10 | Student3 |
+--------+-------+----------+----------+
```

I have this table with a list of students appearing in a particular exam with different subjects.

The total subject is the total number of subjects the exam has. Pass represents the status of student passed in any subject and fail represents the status of student failed in any subject.

Now the problem is the total count of the passed ,fail and passed percentage of students in the exam. If a student fails in any subject he/she is fails.

I tried with lot of things but could not get the result.

This is what I'm getting:

```
+----------+------------+------+------+--------------+
| STUDENT  | TOTAL_SUBJ | PASS | FAIL | PASS_PERCENT |
+----------+------------+------+------+--------------+
| Student3 |          2 |    1 |    1 |        50.00 |
| Student4 |          2 |    0 |    2 |         0.00 |
| Student5 |          2 |    2 |    0 |       100.00 |
| Student8 |          2 |    1 |    0 |       100.00 |
+----------+------------+------+------+--------------+
```

Can any one give a good solution for it?

Here is my Query for the above output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT exreslt.SID AS STUDENT,
COUNT(exsubj.EXSUBJID) AS TOTAL_SUBJ,
SUM(exreslt.RESULT >= exsubj.PASS) AS PASS,
SUM(exreslt.RESULT < exsubj.PASS) AS FAIL,

ROUND(SUM(exreslt.RESULT >= exsubj.PASS)*100/ COUNT(exreslt.SID),2) AS 'PASS_PERCENT'
FROM EXAMSUBJ AS exsubj
STRAIGHT_JOIN EXAMRESULT AS exreslt
WHERE exsubj.EXSUBJID = exreslt.EXSUBJID AND exsubj.EXMID = exreslt.EXMID AND exsubj.EXMID=4 GROUP BY exreslt.SID ;
```

I want the output to be

```
+----------+------------+------+------+--------------+
| STUDENT  | TOTAL_SUBJ | PASS | FAIL | PASS_PERCENT |
+----------+------------+------+------+--------------+
|       4  |          2 |    2 |    2 |        50.00 |
+----------+------------+------+------+--------------+
```

If any student fails in any one subject he will be count as fail or else he will be pass.

Comment: Is that first table the input or the broken output? Can you show the input data, and then what you *expect* to see as output?

Comment: So show the input, otherwise we have to guess what you're working from.

Comment: Could you enter the expected result? I fail to see what your are hoping to achieve

Comment: Are you saying that `PASS_PERCENT` should be 0 if `FAIL` >= 1 regardless of `PASS`?

Comment: yes...and i want the total count of FAIL and PASS depending upon FAIL>=1

Comment: You *really* need to *show* what you want to get out. I've taken the liberty of changing your screenshots to text, so you can copy'n'paste the table and make the output look correct.

Comment: @Aaraadhana you need to clarify your question. to me, your question is too unclear. the best thing to do is to edit your question, put the tables used, their schema (or structure of your table), sample records, and your expected output. thanks.

Comment: your fields are `RESULT` , `EXMID` , `EXSUBJID` , `SID`. How do you know if the student has failed or passed?

Comment: @johntotetwoo: SUM(exreslt.RESULT < exsubj.PASS) AS FAIL will check it for this condition

Comment: @Cylindric:exsubj.PASS is minimum pass marks of the subject. So i have put two condition to get the total pass and fail of each student in the exam.

Comment: EXSUBJID is the subject ID of each subject.PASS is the minimum pass marks .RESULT is the marks obtained by the student.SID is the student ID

Comment: @Cylindric: Sir i have updated my question with the desire output.